# Kafka: Poll vs Pause and Resume

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a `KafkaConsumer` that need to read from a topic in some irregular interval. I have a mechanism that indicates it is time to see if the messages are available (outer loop). This mechanism dictates when we can start polling from a consumer again as you can see below.

```
while(true){ 
  // some event indicate that messages can be processed 
  val done = false
  while(!done) {
   val rec = consumer.poll
   if (rec.nonEmpty)
   // process
    else
     done = true
  }
}
```

I am aware once we stop polling, we will stop sending a heartbeat and `session.timeout.ms` will be reached eventually which will mark a consumer as inactive. What is the impact of just polling on a consumer marked as inactive (using code above) vs manually pausing and resuming (using code below)?

```
while(true){ 
  // some event indicate that messages can be processed 
  consumer.resume
  val done = false
  while(!done) {
   val rec = consumer.poll
   if (rec.nonEmpty)
   // process
    else {
     done = true
     consumer.pause
   }
  }
}
```

I am guessing polling on inactive consumer triggers rebalance (which is expensive and time consuming) as they are re-joining the group, would that happen if we pause and resume?

Thanks

Comment: Consumer activeness can be controlled with relatively higher configuration of 'max.poll.interval.ms' and 'session.timeout.ms', to keeping higher value you will avoid the re-balancing and re-assignment of partitions.

Comment: I am aware and that's not my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/clients/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause-java.util.Collection-

> Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

So it seems like a better option than having the consumers timeout and rebalance due to not polling.